# Are contrast checkers really accurate?

Tags: accessibility, contrast

Is **[WCAG AA level](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG2AA-Conformance)** truly necessary? I'm having difficulty making optimal contrast choices, and honestly, bold text, even at 16px, appears much more readable than regular text. Additionally, I often struggle to ensure both the button/background contrast and the button/text contrast meet the necessary standards. It feels absurd.
[I also found this, when working on a project.](https://www.bounteous.com/insights/2019/03/22/orange-you-accessible-mini-case-study-color-ratio)

I really want to learn more all about it.

Comment: *"It feels absurd"*, according to your eyesight, right? You are making a judgement call on whether this is necessary based on what **you** can see.

Comment: Alright, I dunno if it's allowed to ask follow-up questions, but is it OK to break this rule only for navbars or other branded elements?

Comment: That's kind of a philosophical question. All of WCAG is voluntary. They are "guidelines" to help your website (or other digital asset) be available to as many people as possible. You can ignore as much of it as you want. You just have to ask yourself which groups of people is it ok to prevent access to my website? Note, however, that even though WCAG itself is voluntary, most countries, states, and other territorial areas have laws *requiring* accessibility and those laws typically point to WCAG as the way to measure compliance. So ignoring WCAG for part of the UI *could* get you sued.

Comment: Also keep in mind that WCAG is not just about disabilities. While following WCAG does make the website accessible to more people, it also "**make(s) Web content more usable to users in general**", quoted from the first paragraph of [WCAG](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/).

Comment: There should be a flag for link-only *questions* too.

Comment: Hi @Gugalcrom123 you said *"I really want to learn more all about it"* okay, here are two articles that are intended as intro/overviews and (I hope) are good entry points for what is a fairly abstract and complicated subject: A comprehensive overview in [*Realities and Myths of Color*](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2022/09/realities-myths-contrast-color/) AND an intro to the candidate WCAG2 replacement, [*Why APCA*](https://git.apcacontrast.com/documentation/WhyAPCA) ... Hit me up with questions if you have any.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you're right—the WCAG 2 colour contrast algorithm is not a very good representation of the way humans actually perceive contrast. Perhaps the most prototypical example is the colour of a text label on an orange background, where the algorithm says that black text has higher contrast, but most humans seem to agree that a white label is easier to read. As you also correctly point out, font weight (and size and specific font choices) all affect contrast too, but the algorithm doesn't factor any of those things in.

The good news is that it's set to be replaced in [WCAG 3](https://www.w3.org/TR/wcag-3.0/#visual-contrast-of-text) with [the Accessible Perceptual Contrast Algorithm (APCA)](https://www.myndex.com/APCA/) being developed by Andrew Somers, which much more closely models actual human vision research. In many cases, APCA will recommend that designers make the exact opposite choices for foreground colours as WCAG 2 AA has typically required (e.g. white instead of black).

In general, the WCAG 2 guidelines are broken because they reduce a deeply complex topic into a series of "pass" and "fail" ratings, which is far too overly simplistic. As [the APCA website puts it](https://git.apcacontrast.com/documentation/APCA_in_a_Nutshell):

> A key takeaway is that a strict pass/fail with a blanket contrast ratio is not instructive as a guideline, and does not necessarily solve a given user need. In fact, user needs when it comes to contrast are conflicting—what is good for one can be harmful to another. This is even true of font size.

There's [a very good write-up of the differences between the two algorithms with examples](https://medium.com/@think_ui/why-color-contrast-is-not-as-black-and-white-as-it-seems-94197a72b005) from our very own [Roger Attrill](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/6046/roger-attrill), with some representative examples:

[image: An image showing Twitter blue as a background with white and black foreground text, comparing the WCAG 2 contrast algorithm with APCA. The WCAG 2 algorithm shows black is more accessible, whereas APCA shows white is more accessible]

Note, too, that this issue is [becoming even more important with dark mode](https://git.apcacontrast.com/documentation/WhyAPCA#visual-comparisons) (which is obviously becoming more and more common).

Comment: As a normal-sighted user, this is interesting and actually more accurate, thanks for the answer. I have always found white on teal or orange to be more readable than black, and designed my applications around this knowing it won't pass AA. Waiting for it to come to the Chrome DevTools.

Comment: WCAG 3 is still some ways off. [Somers himself has proposed an alternative, simpler formula than APCA](https://github.com/w3c/silver/issues/667) which may end up being what ends up recommended instead, so it's hard to say what will end up in our dev tools.

Comment: Hi @KitGrose — Ah yea, the politics of standards... DeltaPhiStar was something of a proof of concept, throwing away some accuracy such as polarity sensitivity and also being more aligned with certain standard maths that are part of the CSS standards/library. Hard to say how things are going to evolve over the next few years at W3C, but there is the separate and independent **Inclusive Reading Technologies Readability Criterion** (IRT-RC) and the current working draft is https://readtech.org/ARC/

Comment: @Myndex Thanks for your input (and all the work you're doing in this space)! I wasn't familiar with the IRT-RC, so thanks for sharing. My biggest frustration with this whole business right now is that until the introduction of its replacement, WCAG 2.x (along with regulatory obligations to ensure at least an AA rating) effectively forces us as designers to produce designs that are measurably worse for our users.

Comment: Hi @KitGrose regulatory obligations are occasionally mischaracterized. For instance in the United States the 508 rules have built "alternative facilitation" exception. Ultimately what's legal is ***actual*** accessibility, more so then adhering to an arbitrary threshold associated with flawed math. There is "BridgePCA" which uses APCA technology but it's modified and has guidelines to align as well to WCAG2. While you lose the flexibility of APCA, it does fix the worst problems with WCAG2's false passes of dark colors. Demonstrator:  https://bridgepca.com

Comment: @Myndex Naturally regulatory environments differ significantly globally. In Australia (at least), Government agencies are [required to meet WCAG 2.1 as part of the Digital Service Standard](https://www.dta.gov.au/help-and-advice/digital-service-standard/digital-service-standard-criteria/9-make-it-accessible) (there is no exemption for areas where those guidelines are provably lacking).

Comment: Hi @KitGrose I see it says "WCAG Level 2.1" (sic) 2.1 isn't a level, and I've been frustrated trying to find an AU policy that said anything other than level A... That said, for AA and AAA, BridgePCA is designed to meet all (with a loss in flexibility vs APCA proper). But also, only one layout/palette needs to conform to WCAG 2.1 — for instance a light mode, provided there's a control to switch just say a dark mode, the other modes can use an alternate method.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is. You may have come across a very specific use case that works with orange (and perhaps some shades of green), but those are exceptions, not the norm. The contrast ratio is based on mathematics, and subjective biases can exist since not all eyes perceive things in the same way. However, as a general rule, the [**contrast ratio formula**](https://medium.muz.li/the-science-of-color-contrast-an-expert-designers-guide-33e84c41d156) functions effectively for the majority of cases.

```
Contrast ratios can range from 1 to 21 (commonly written 1:1 to 21:1).

(L1 + 0.05) / (L2 + 0.05), where:

L1 represents the relative luminance of the lighter color, and L2 represents
the relative luminance of the darker color.
```

So, is it necessary? Yes, both for individuals with visual impairments and for legal reasons. If someone were to sue a company due to accessibility issues with an application (which has happened numerous times since it is mandatory), lawyers would simply present that formula as evidence, regardless of subjective opinions regarding alternative options.

Finally, I understand that it may be a bit annoying, but to be completely honest, it only requires 2 or 3 color changes, let's say 10, and you'll achieve an accessible design.

Comment: Hi @Devin you said: *"functions effectively for the majority of cases"* Well, third party independent testing with a randomized selection of thousands of color pairs showed that WCAG2 incorrectly passes 47% of color pairs and incorrectly fails around 22%.  The bigger problem however is that it can actually makes things worse for certain color vision deficiencies, particular protanopia. The problem with oranges and reds is not an edge case, and it's harmful to readability for protans. But the more pressing problem is the fact that WCAG2 cannot calculate correctly for dark mode.